# Página recarregando após clique em botão

Tags: jquery

Estou com um problema após acionar um botão na minha página, utilizando Jquery.

Após o click, uma função deveria ser feita e depois o resultado seria exibido na tela, porém eu notei que após clicar no botão, a função é executada e o resultado mostrado porém em fração de segundos, e a página é recarregada em seguida.

segue o HTML e JS referentes a essa parte :

```
<div class="list-group" id='allResultBasal'>
        
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active"  id='basalHomem'>
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">Homem</h5>
            <small><span id='subClassM'>Clique para entender</span></small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">
              <br>
              Seu Consumo Calórico Basal é:<br>
              <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
              <span id='resultHomem'>   </span>
              
          </p>
          <small></small>
        </a>
       
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start" id='basalMulher'> 
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">Mulher</h5>
            <small class="text-muted"><span  id='subClassM'>Clique para entender</span></small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1"><br>Seu Consumo Calórico Basal é:<br></p>
          <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
        </a>
    </div>
```

o JS :

```
$("#botaoBasal").click(function(){
    var pesoB = $("#inputPassword3").val();
    var alturaB = $('#inputPassword2').val();
    var idadeB = $('#inputEmail3').val();    
    var generoB = $("input[name='gridRadios']:checked").val();
    var basal ='nothing';
    
    if (generoB == 'h'){

        var basal = 66.5 + (13.75 * pesoB) + (5 * alturaB ) - (6.8 * idadeB);
        //66,5 + (13,75 x Peso) + (5,0 x Altura em cm) – (6,8 x Idade).

        $('#basalHomem').css('visibility', 'visible');
        //$('#resultHomem').text(basal +'kcal/dia');
        

    }else if (generoB == 'm'){
        var basal = 665.1 + (9.56 * pesoB) + (1.8 * alturaB) - (4.7 * idadeB);
        // 665,1 + (9,56 x Peso) + (1,8 x Altura em cm) – (4,7 x Idade).

        $('#basalMulher').css('visibility', 'visible');
        //$('#resultMulher').text(basal +'kcal/dia');

    }
    console.log(basal);

   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema provavelmente acontece porque você está usando tags `<a href="#">` no botão.

É importante frisar que o snippet de HTML que você publicou **não inclui o botão que ativa sua função, ou se contém ele não possui o ID botaoBasal**, e isso torna a solução a seguir apenas um palpite.

A tag `a` em html serve para direcionar o navegador para algum lugar, e é dispensável caso a função do botão seja única e exclusivamente executar Javascript. O Listener continua funcionando mesmo quando vinculado a um elemento diferente. Dependendo do seu ambiente o `href="#"` pode ser entendido como "esta página", e então ele redireciona para a mesma página, parecendo um recarregamento.

Duas são as soluções, uma correta e uma fácil:

A fácil é adicionar a variável `event`no seu jQuery e depois cancelar ela. Fica algo assim:

```
// Aqui a gente passa a variável "event", que captura detalhes de onde foi dado o clique
    $("#botaoBasal").click(function( event ){
        
        // Seu código aqui
        
        // Agora cancelamos a execução padrão da tag, que é o redirecionamento, com o método preventDefault
        event.preventDefault();

    });
```

Agora, a solução correta mesmo seria remover a sua tag `a` completamente, e alocar o seu ID Seletor no próprio botão:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="minhas classes aqui" id="botaoBasal">
      Verificar Basal
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```